# Generating empty HTML Mochawesome report from populated JSON file in Cypress

Tags: cypress, mochawesome

I am trying to generate one mochawesome report that contains all results of the spec files in my Cypress test suite.

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
    "test": "npx cypress run",
    "combine-reports": "mochawesome-merge cypress/reports/mochawesome-report/*.json > mochareports/report.json",
    "generate-report": "marge mochareports/*.json --reportDir mochawesome --assetsDir mochawesome/assets --reportPageTitle index.html"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^9.5.4",
    "mocha": "^9.2.2",
    "mochawesome": "^7.1.3",
    "mochawesome-merge": "^4.2.1",
    "mochawesome-report-generator": "^6.2.0"
  }
}
```

`npm run test` works as expected.

Running `npm run combine-reports`, creates `mochareports/report.json` as expected. I've opened the file in a text editor & it's populated with test stats, results, etc.

Running `npm run generate-report` displays `Reports saved` on the console.
If I open the HTML page (`cypress/reports/mochareports/report.html`) in VS Code, HTML is appearing. However, if I open it in a web browser, I get a blank HTML page & the below console error:

[image]

The HTML report is being generated, but for some reason is showing up as a blank page in a web browser.

Can someone please show me how to resolve this?

Comment: Just in case it helps someone in the future, we had an almost empty html doc from our build pipeline. Turns out we were only exporting the html file, the js actually builds the doc once it's rendered, so make sure you have the js exported, (and css if you want it to look nice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you also add the cypress.json file, but I will explain with a simple example,

Here is my cypress.json report configuration

```
{
  "reporter": "cypress-multi-reporters",
  "reporterOptions": {
    "reporterEnabled": "mochawesome",
    "mochawesomeReporterOptions": {
      "reportDir": "cypress/reports/mocha",
      "quite": true,
      "overwrite": false,
      "html": false,
      "json": true
    }
  }
}
```

And in your package.json I do not see the script to combine all json files
for ex:

```
"scripts": {
    "clean:reports": "rm -R -f cypress/reports && mkdir cypress/reports && mkdir cypress/reports/mochareports ",
    "pretest": "npm run clean:reports",
    "scripts": "cypress run",
    "combine-reports": "mochawesome-merge cypress/reports/mocha/*.json > cypress/reports/mochareports/report.json",
"generate-report": "marge cypress/reports/mochareports/report.json -f report -o cypress/reports/mochareports -- inline",
    "posttest": "npm run combine-reports && npm run generate-report",
    "test" : "npm run scripts || npm run posttest"
  }
```

You can get some idea here also - https://medium.com/tech-learn-share/attach-screenshot-into-mochawesome-html-report-in-cypress-ca3792081474